# Unresolved Error in AppDelegate about the mainView (xcode11)

Tags: swift, xcode11

I'm trying to build my own time management app and got following error in my `AppDelegate.swift`.

I already tried to find spelling mistakes or other errors in my code, but was not successful.

Should be a basic `Use of unresolved Identifier` error but somehow I do not find the solution.

First question here^^ Let me know when you need further information. Thanks for helping!

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        if let window = self.window {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            let nav = UINavigationController()
            let mainView = ViewController()
            nav.viewControllers = [mainView]

            window.rootViewController = nav
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // Other default AppDelegate functions
}
```

`Use of unresolved identifier 'ViewController'`

**EDIT:** *ViewController code*

```
import UIKit

enum MyTheme {
    case light
    case dark
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var theme = MyTheme.dark

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "My Calender"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent=false
        self.view.backgroundColor=Style.bgColor
        view.addSubview(calenderView)
        calenderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
        calenderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive=true
        calenderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive=true
        calenderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 365).isActive=true

        let rightBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Light", style: .plain, target: self, action:
        #selector(rightBarBtnAction))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarBtn
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        calenderView.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    @objc func rightBarBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if theme == .dark {
            sender.title = "Dark"
            theme = .light
            Style.themeLight()
        } else {
            sender.title = "Light"
            theme = .dark
            Style.themeDark()
        }

        self.view.backgroundColor=Style.bgColor
        calenderView.changeTheme()
    }

    let calenderView: CalenderView = {
        let v=CalenderView(theme: MyTheme.dark)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return v
    }()
}
```

Comment: Do you have a custom class called `ViewController`? Does the file containing it have its `Target Membership` marked properly?

Comment: Yes I have the class ViewController.swift and both have the same Target Membership. Thats why I do not understand the error.

Comment: Try to define ViewController first with storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>).

Comment: Post the contents of `ViewController.swift`

Comment: I changed the post and updated it

Comment: Post the project for download.

Comment: Check that YourClass is part of the project: go to project definition > Build Phases, expand Compile Sources and find `YourClass` in the list. If it's not there, you can add it from the same interface.